# Boto3 Glue in AWS Glue ETL Job

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am running AWS Glue ETL job (Pyspark) where I have created a boto3 client of Glue to start the crawler and do some other PySpark processing. The issue is that the Glue job keeps on running after `start_crawler` is called. It neither gives any error, nor ends or starts the crawler. My code snippet is below:

```
import sys
import boto3
import time

glue_client = boto3.client('glue', region_name = 'us-east-1')
crawler_name = 'test_crawler'
    
print('Starting crawler...')
print(crawler_name)
glue_client.start_crawler(Name=crawler_name)
```

Whereas the same code if I execute in the Python Shell Glue Job, it successfully starts the crawler and the job terminates. What am I doing wrong here or do I need to do something specific w.r.t Glue ETL job?

Edit: My Glue job has a Glue connection attached to it which I am using to connect to RDS. If I remove this, then this code works fine. But I need this connection to be there to connect to RDS. Any help?

Comment: can you remove the crawler piece and test whether you are able to read/write with RDS ?

Comment: This could be due to the VPC settings, the RDS should be within a VPC that's causing the connection to timeout.

This link may be helpful https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/connecting-to-and-running-etl-jobs-across-multiple-vpcs-using-a-dedicated-aws-glue-vpc/

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, but just a tip.
I don´t think its a good idea to start the crawler in the same job. You don´t have control when the crawler finishes and if it finishes well.
What I do is create an AWS Step Function and create workflows, first the glue job and after it finishes, the crawler would be the next step. That way you can control and monitor the process.

Comment: Crawler is just an example. Any glue/athena boto3 call does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error and moved my ETL jobs to aws glue 3.0, and now boto3 client is working for me. let me know if this doesn't solve your problem